# How do I sleep for a few seconds in Smalltalk Pharo, and be able to interrupt this?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm debugging some keyboard event code and I want to loop with a sleep (to give me a chance to create the keyboard event), however when I do this Pharo won't let me quit with Command-. so debugging is difficult. I had to wait 500 seconds to fix something in the code below...

```
100 timesRepeat: [ 
    Transcript show: 'Type an a... '.
    (Delay forSeconds: 5) wait.
    (Sensor keyPressed: $a) ifTrue: [ Transcript show: 'you pressed a' ].
]
```

So how can I make Command-. work, or is there something more suitable than `(Delay forSeconds: 5) wait.`?

Comment: I'm running Pharo 2.0 on Mac OS X.

Comment: Could you try in a 3.0 image? I think we recently fixed some stuff in the global interrupt

Comment: I'll check out 3.0 at some point, however I need something that works in Pharo 2.0 as that's the platform we're using. Are there plans for Pharo 2.1 with these sorts of fixes in?

Comment: It does work in Pharo 3.0.

Comment: I added a [bug report](https://pharo.fogbugz.com/default.asp?10569) that should improve the situation for 2.0. Until then I can only recommend a poor man's solution: press CMD-. several times and hope it interrupts.

Comment: The [bug fix](https://pharo.fogbugz.com/default.asp?10569) has been integrated. Could you try again?

Comment: It works in the latest Pharo 2.0 build :)

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in Squeak on Mac OS X (using `peekKeyboardEvent`, it does not have `keyPressed:`). So it's not your code's fault, interrupting this should work fine.

Comment: Yes it works for me in Squeak 4.4 too, but I need something that works in Pharo 2.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely shure this works in Pharo, but in Squeak you can just fork your code in a new process, so it does not block the UI:

```
[
    100 timesRepeat: [ 
        Transcript show: 'Type an a... '.
        (Delay forSeconds: 5) wait.
        (Sensor keyPressed: $a) ifTrue: [ Transcript show: 'you pressed a' ].
    ].
] fork.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started with Pharo and it seems what you're *really* running into is still an issue among beginners (myself included). Looking at your code it seems you want to the `Transcript` to update every 5 seconds. Here is how to do it (comments included to make certain nuances clear).

```
| process | "If you're running outside a playground, you should declare the variable, otherwise you should not declare it because it needs to bind to the playground itself"

process := [ 
    100 timesRepeat: [ 
        Transcript show: 'Type an a... '; cr. "I like a newline, hence the cr"
        (Delay forSeconds: 5) wait.
        "In Pharo 10, the following doesn't work, still need to figure out how to do this"
        "(Sensor keyPressed: $a) ifTrue: [ Transcript show: 'you pressed a' ]."
    ]
] fork.

process terminate. "You can run this to terminate the process inside the playground"
process suspend. "Also possible"
process resume.
```